# Closed Volume - Initialization Error - Modelica

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I try to model a simplified case which consists of a SweptVolume and a ClosedVolume. When piston moves downwards then closedvolume should fill with water, when piston move upwards the fluid will flow into the piston. But I get initialization errors. Could you help me to handle this error? Thanks in advance!

> Residual function evaluation failed at initial point for "1"
> From Hochdruckreiniger4_1:       Jacobian evaluation failed at initial point for "1"
> From Hochdruckreiniger4_1:     Failed to find a consistent solution in event iteration in "1", 0 at        0.0000000000000000E+000
> From Hochdruckreiniger4_1:   Residual function evaluation failed at initial point for "2" "#r108#"
> From Hochdruckreiniger4_1: Initialization failed.

```
model Hochdruckreiniger4
    //Declaration(s)
    Real V_max = 0.000003;
    Real V_tod = 0.000002;
    Real N = 2800;
    replaceable package medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater( );
    //Component(s)
    inner Modelica.Fluid.System system;
    Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume volume (nPorts = 1, redeclare package Medium = medium, V = 0.05);
    Modelica.Fluid.Machines.SweptVolume Swept1 (
        pistonCrossArea = 0.0001131,
        clearance = 0.00000250621,
        redeclare package Medium = Modelica.Media.Water.StandardWater,
        nPorts = 1,
        use_portsData = false,
        massDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial,
        energyDynamics = Modelica.Fluid.Types.Dynamics.DynamicFreeInitial,
        p_start = 1e5,
        use_T_start = true,
        T_start = 293.15,
        V(start = 0.005),
        m(start = 0.005));
    Modelica.Mechanics.Translational.Sources.Position Posit1 (exact = true, useSupport = false);
    Modelica.Blocks.Sources.Sine Sine1 (
        amplitude = 0.005567,
        freqHz = 46.66,
        offset = 0.005567,
        phase = -Modelica.Constants.pi/4);


equation
    //Connection(s)
    connect(Sine1.y, Posit1.s_ref);
    connect(Posit1.flange, Swept1.flange);
    connect(Swept1.ports, volume.ports);
end  Hochdruckreiniger4;
```

[image]

Comment: It works. Could you explain why must I add the diamater to the closedvolume?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After changing the volume's parameters (adding a diameter to the port) the model seems to work. This results in the following code for the `volume` model:

```
Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.ClosedVolume volume(nPorts = 1, redeclare package Medium = medium, V = 0.05, portsData={Modelica.Fluid.Vessels.BaseClasses.VesselPortsData(diameter=0.001)});
```

The simulation still gives some warnings regarding pressure (probably because the estimated diameter of 1mm does not make a lot of sense), but the pressure in the volume does not look totally off.

Some background (though I'm not very experienced with the Fluid package):
For `use_portsData = true` the diameter needs to be specified as it does not have any start or default value. In Dymola the simulation would not even start without a value for it. Actually there should be at least a warning if there is no value set. Assuming that it takes 0 as value for the diameter it would be reasonable that the model brakes, as there cannot be any flow into the volume.

As an alternative it could be possible to set `use_portsData` to false. I think this will result in no resistance at the volumes connector. Still it good practice to not connect volume-type models directly, but always have a resistance-type model in between. Actually it is best to have volume- and resistance-type models in alternating order.